# I guess I earned 2410 reputation today

Tags: support, reputation, association-bonus

[image]

I guess today was a good day.

Seriously though - anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Omg, I posted this "question" for lulz, now everybody hatin' with the downvotes

Comment: It is not [Friday](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21413/158100)...

Comment: @rene Now it is!

Comment: @Magisch You waited a whole day to make that comment, right?  ;)

Answer (score 18):

This is from you earning the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus). It looks like you passed 200 reputation on Stack Overflow today, which would trigger it. From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting **+100 reputation bonus** to get you past basic new user restrictions. **This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account**, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

Emphasis mine. You're a member of 24 different sites and, since each one of them earned 100 reputation, it added 2400 new reputation, all of which was reported in your reputation notifications. You can verify this by looking at your [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1325575/nino-%C5%A0kopac?tab=reputation), where you can see:

```
+100    30 mins ago     assoc   Association Bonus
```